# Check if swiping on mobile screen loads a new element

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

On Our mobile application, we have several screens where we need to swipe on the screen to view the element or swiping loads a new element. In our code, whenever we go to check whether an element is present or not, we call a method to check the current set of elements on the screen, then swipe and again read all the elements on the screen after swiping. Now, compare the last element on two lists to check if a new element loaded or not. If no new element loaded then we conclude that the element we are looking for is not loading on the screen. Below is the code I wrote for this purpose. This code should identify if swiping is loading a new element or not.

The problem is with the step where I am reading all the elements and loading to the list. This step becomes very heavy and on occasion, holds the code execution for more than 5 minutes.

Can someone please suggest if I can do something better here.

```
public synchronized boolean isScrollingLoadsNewElement (AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver)
    {
        boolean isNewElementLoaded = false;
        System.out.println("inside the new method to scroll and check new element");
        //declare a list to accept all the elements on current screen
        //go to the end of the list to read the last element. Store in a variable
    this.driver = driver;

    List<MobileElement> lAllElements = this.driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));

    System.out.println("list of element before swiping has been read");
    MobileElement lastElement = lAllElements.get(lAllElements.size()-1);

    //scroll and then again read the list of all elements.
    //read the last element on the list and then compare the elements on above 2 steps. 
    //if the elements are different than return true else false.
    swipeScreen(driver);
    List<MobileElement> lAllElementsAfterSwipe = this.driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
    System.out.println("list of element after swiping has been read");
    MobileElement lastElementAfterSwipe = lAllElementsAfterSwipe.get(lAllElementsAfterSwipe.size()-1);

    if (lastElementAfterSwipe.equals(lastElement))
        isNewElementLoaded = false;
    else
        isNewElementLoaded = true;
    return isNewElementLoaded;

}
```

Comment: Have answered it, let me know if that helps :)

Comment: @Sameer Arora Your method will definitely work. We had same implementation earlier and it failed due to hard coded counter on few test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching the last element before swipe and first element after swipe, you should check that the required element is displayed on the page by checking its list size.

Lets say there are 4 elements on your page and after loading, 5th element gets displayed, going by your approach you will be checking that the 5th element is not same as the 4th element and you would be passing the test case, however this would not give you the certainty that the element which got displayed was the element that you were looking for, because that 5th element can be any other element which was not meant to be displayed on the page but going by your logic, the test case would pass.

So, you should get the xpath of the element you are looking for and then after every swipe you should check the element list size as the element list size would be greater than 0 when it gets displayed on the page and you should limit the swipe to a limit so that after that number of swipes, you should return the boolean as false, else the loop will go on in an infinite state in order to check the element presence.

Your code logic should be something like:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("mention the xpath of the element that needs to be found"));
boolean elementLoaded = false;
int swipeCount = 0;
// Taking the swipeCount limit as 5 here
while (!elementLoaded && swipeCount < 5) {
    if (element.size() == 0) {
        // Swipe the screen
        swipe(driver);
        swipeCount++;
    } else {
        elementLoaded = true;
    }
}
return elementLoaded;
```

Comment: The only concern I have with your method is that you are restricting the swipe count to 5. We had similar implementation as yours and it failed on a screen where the element was supposed to load after 8 swipes. Hence, I wanted to change this to something dynamic.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the step to read all elements on the screen. Now I am able to directly read the last element on the screen.
    MobileElement lastElement = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[last()]"));

Now the problem is on this line - 
if (lastElementAfterSwipe.equals(lastElement))
it is always returning me true, even though while debugging, I can see that the two elements are different.

Comment: You can change the count of swipe according to your requirements, you can take it 10 as well to be on the safe side but you would be certain that if the test case passes the element is there however if you go by your approach your test case will pass even though there is some new and undesirable element on the page.

Comment: And in the new approach you are taking now, you would be checking only one swipe that the new element is different or not but there can be a scenario that after 3-4 swipes, the element which is supposed to appear did not appear, so you have to define some number of swipes to actual the desired element presence on the page.

Comment: My bad that I did not mention that the above method is being called from a while loop. So, here goes the entire logic. Check if element is present, in not then from inside the while loop call the above method (note that above method is calling a method to swipe on screen). If after swipe a new element is getting loaded then there is chance of finding the element I am looking for. So, inside the original while loop, again check if desired element is found. If it has been found then break out of while loop. If not found then again call above method to check if scrolling loads new one.

Answer (score 0):

Rather storing all elements and comparing the with next state, just get one element after next scroll make sure that element should not present in the screen

Note : though I do not have much context on your app

Comment: I am not sure if am following the suggestion. In my case, I am trying to make a decision on whether I should continue to scroll or stop scrolling for finding my expected element. That is why I am storing all the elements on the screen before scrolling and then again store all the elements after scrolling. After that, I compare the last element on two list to check if scrolling is loading any new element or not. If scrolling does not load new element then I am not going to find my element and my method will return false.

Comment: Ok, in this case you no need to store all the elements every time, instead create the xpath or locator accordingly which you need to find on the screen & match the element till then you can screen put while loop will work